# How to import an existing private key into AWS KMS?

Tags: signature, private-key, keystore, aws, kms

Is there a way to import into AWS Key Management Service an already existing private key so I can sign transactions with that wallet? I have found some tutorials online (like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwL1UiMJU7M) but they only show you how to create a new key from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import an existing private key into AWS KMS you have to follow these steps:

1. Create a `.pem` file based on your private key:

```
var KeyEncoder = require('key-encoder');
var keyEncoder = new KeyEncoder.default('secp256k1');

var pemPrivateKey = keyEncoder.encodePrivate('0b2ecdafce86f9969d94b73fd9ba6dd781a4e271adcda41e343c61b711567155', 'raw', 'pem')

console.log(pemPrivateKey);
```

2. Set variables to download the `PublicKey` and `ImportToken` of the wrap key created above, making it easier for us to generate the key material that satisfies the requirements:

```
export KEY=`aws kms get-parameters-for-import --region {{AWS_REGION}} \
--key-id {{KEY_ID}} \
--wrapping-algorithm RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256 \
--wrapping-key-spec RSA_2048 \
--query '{Key:PublicKey,Token:ImportToken}' \
--output text`
echo $KEY | awk '{print $1}' > PublicKey.b64
echo $KEY | awk '{print $2}' > ImportToken.b64
openssl enc -d -base64 -A -in PublicKey.b64 -out PublicKey.bin
openssl enc -d -base64 -A -in ImportToken.b64 -out ImportToken.bin
```

3. Convert the private key to `Base64` and generate a binary file, we can accomplish this in one step with the appropriate command:

```
cat ec-secp256k1-priv-key.pem | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform der \
-nocrypt > ec-secp256k1-priv-key.der
```

4. Next, we use `pkeyutl` to encrypt the generated binary file and generate the required key material:

```
openssl pkeyutl \
-encrypt \
-in ec-secp256k1-priv-key.der \
-out EncryptedKeyMaterial.bin \
-inkey PublicKey.bin \
-keyform DER \
-pubin -encrypt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256
```

5. Upload the following files to AWS KMS:

- `EncryptedKeyMaterial.bin` as "Wrapped key material"
- `ImportToken.bin` as "Import token"

For more information you can check this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/import-ethereum-private-keys-to-aws-kms